# colorbox refreshing parent window without closing popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I am using colorbox for showing pop ups. Is this possible to reload parent window without closing pop. I mean I want to do actions/events in the pop up and the changes should be displayed at parent window.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely play with the elements in the page from within the colorbox.  You can't, however, "refresh the parent window" as you stated in the question title, because then you will also lose the colorbox (which is a part of that page).

But judging from the rest of your question, you simply want to make changes in the page. If your colorbox is not in an iframe (e.g., you have not explicity set the option `iframe:true`) then it's pretty straightforward.  Just create event handlers that are called from actions performed in the colorbox.

If you are setting the colorbox to open an iframe, there's a couple things to be aware of:

- The iframe page (the contents of your colorbox) must be within the same domain
- Use the `parent.` in the iframe's JS that references the parent page

Here's an example of the colorbox code you would have in the iframe page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.internalColorboxLink").click(function() {
        parent.$("body").append(
            parent.$("<div/>").text("MY NEW TEXT")
        );
    });
});
```

In fact, this is the almost the same code as would be in the inline colorbox (that is, the js in the parent page).  Simply remove the `parent` references.

I can post more concrete examples if you update your question with exactly what you want to do.